# SEO-дружелюбный блог на MODX Revo

Tags: url, modx, seo

Требуется создать блог с SEO-дружелюбными URL вида:

```
site.ru/nazvanie-statii
```

Что легко решается в MODX при создании обычных ресурсов в контейнере. Но. Если использовать сторонние расширения для создания и управления блогом например расширение `Articles`, получаются ссылки вида:

```
site.ru/blog/nazvanie-statii
```

Где `blog` - можно переименовать как угодно, но избавиться от вложенности в него и удалить - невозможно.

Подскажите, как создать seo-оптимизированный блог на MODX, подскажите куда копать(расширения, и т.п.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я помню в ресурсе во вкладке Настройки страницы есть чекбокс "Участвует в URL" и если вы оттуда галочку уберете, то он перестанет отображаться в адресе.